# Why am I getting this If statement problem?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am getting the error "End If Without Block If" problem in VBA. Followin is my code. Could someone help me find out the mistake I am making?

```
Function ProjectedProductionPlan(Coverage As Double, Sales As Variant, ProjectedStock As Double) As Double
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim ResidualBalance As Double
    Dim ProjectedPlan As Double
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Single
    Dim s As Single

    count = Sales.count
    s = 0
    ResidualBalance = ProjectedStock
    i = 1
        If Coverage < 1 Then
            ProjectedPlan = (Sales(i) * Coverage) - ResidualBalance
          ElseIf Coverage = 1 Then
            ProjectedPlan = Sales(i) - ResidualBalance
          Else
            For k = 1 To count
                 Do Until k - Coverage > 0
                        x = k
                        y = Coverage - x
                        s = Sales(k) + s
                 Loop
            Exit For
        End If
            ProjectedPlan = s + (Sales(x + 1) * y)

End Function
```

Comment: Change `Exit For` to: `Next` to get rid of the compile error. But I feel you'll end up in an endless loop. You probably want a `If` statement inside the `For` loop. And when `TRUE` use an `Exit For` **within** the `For` loop and ditching the `Do Until ... Loop` doing so.

Comment: Can this question be closed then? @Mirza

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment:

To get rid of the compile error, you'll need to change `Exit For` into `Next` to create an actual iteration whereas `Exit For` is simply a statement ***within*** the loop to ***Exit*** the loop. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) is MS-documentation on `For...Next` loops.

However, you also make use of a `Do Until...Loop`. As I see your code, repairing the above would immediately throw your code in an infinite loop since no variable (neither `k` nor `coverage`) get's adjusted. So my suggestion would be to include an `IF` statement inside your `For...Next` loop instead. For example like this:

```
For k = 1 To count
    If k - Coverage > 0 Then
        Exit For
    Else
        x = k
        y = Coverage - x
        s = Sales(k) + s
    End If
Next
```

I've not checked the rest of your code to see if implementing this is actually what you needed.

***Small sidenote:*** using `Integer` data type variables is only going to bite you at one point. Use `Long` instead.